# Storage and parameter size limitations of smart contract?

Tags: smart-contracts, fees, storage, burn, parameter

Got a few questions regarding storage limitations of smart contract.

1. What is the maximum number of bytes of data that I can send for a single transaction?
2. Is there a size limit to the storage of a smart contract?

Answer (score 14):

## 1. Maximum parameter size per transaction

The maximum
   number of bytes per transaction for a single transaction is limited
   several constants, in particular an upper size of for operations
   `max_operation_data_length` and the hard gas limits for operations
   and blocks (a block contains a set of operations):

```
  "max_operation_data_length": 16384,
  "hard_gas_limit_per_operation": "800000",
  "hard_gas_limit_per_block": "8000000",
  "cost_per_byte": "1000",
  "hard_storage_limit_per_operation": "60000",
```

These constants can be obtained by a RPC call if you have a running node:

```
tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants | jq
```

Presumably `max_operation_data_length` is in bytes, meaning that you
have a an upper limit of of ~16kB for the parameter per
transaction. You would also have to remove the size needed other data
in transaction, such as sender, recipient, etc.

The gas limits `hard_gas_limit_per_block` and
`hard_gas_limit_per_operation` indirectly limit both maximum storage
and transaction size. Each time a smart contract is invoked, the node
passes through the following phases:

1. Read binary representation of smart contract code + contract state
   from disk
2. Decode code, storage and input to untyped representation
3. Typecheck code, storage and input
4. Run code
5. Encode storage to untyped repr.
6. (write encoded storage to disk – batched & async)

Each of these phases consumes gas. Larger parameter increases the gas
consumption in phase 2-4. Larger storage increases gas consumption in
phases 1-5.  It follows that storage and parameter size are limited by
the hard gas limits. However, I do not have any hard numbers, but you
could simulate using tezos-client to obtain estimates.

## 2. Maximum storage size per contract

Finally, for your second question, which is already partially
   answered by 1. AFAIK, there is no explicit fixed limit on the storage of a
   smart contract. However, after a
   certain size, the storage of contract can no longer be decoded,
   because doing so would exceed the hard gas limits. Another limiting
   factor is funds. The `costs_per_byte` is currently at 1000
   mutez. This means that each additional kB costs ~1tz (currently ~= 3usd) to store, payed by
   the sender of transaction that increase storage.

We also have to consider the constant
   `hard_storage_limit_per_operation`. Whenever a transaction is
   injected on the network, it is associated with a storage limit.
   Typically, it is set by the user, to ensure that their transaction
   does not provoke an unintended amount of storage burn. If the size
   of the storage size diff resulting from applying the transaction
   exceeds the storage limit, then the transaction is rejected. The
   constant `hard_storage_limit_per_operation` gives the highest
   storage limit that can be set, and thus also limits the maximum
   storage size increase per transaction. It follows that the
   storage of a contract cannot increase with more than 60000 bytes
   per transaction. Note that such a transaction would cost ~180 usd today.

Comment: When you say "such a txn would cost", are you referring to transaction fees? Gas does not have monetary meaning. Does the amount of txn fee also increase with needed storage amount?

Comment: Indeed, gas does not have a fixed cost. But storage burn has a fixed cost per byte. See here for instance: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/2165/1773 and here http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtouse.html for a full explanation.