# Is there any limitation for Tezos block size?

Tags: node, block

Recently I've discovered that some of the newest blocks have few MB of data. Is there a way predict how big the block may be in the future? Is there any limit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storage and parameter size limitations of smart contract?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2183/storage-and-parameter-size-limitations-of-smart-contract)

Comment: not really, I meant the whole block size in MB

Comment: AFAIK there is no MB limit. Blocks are only limited by total amount of gas used by the operations contained therein. Looking at the constants for mainnet, there is no MB/size constraint.